# Checking if a function has C-linkage at compile-time [unsolvable]

Tags: c++, templates, metaprogramming

Is there any way to check if a given function is declared with C-linkage (that is, with `extern "C"`) at compile-time?

I am developing a plugin system. Each plugin can supply factory functions to the plugin-loading code. However, this has to be done via name (and subsequent use of `GetProcAddress` or `dlsym`). This requires that the functions be declared with C-linkage so as to prevent name-mangling. It would be nice to be able to throw a compiler error if the referred-to function is declared with C++-linkage (as opposed to finding out at runtime when a function with that name does not exist).

Here's a simplified example of what I mean:

```
extern "C" void my_func()
{
}

void my_other_func()
{
}

// Replace this struct with one that actually works
template<typename T>
struct is_c_linkage
{
    static const bool value = true;
};

template<typename T>
void assertCLinkage(T *func)
{
    static_assert(is_c_linkage<T>::value, "Supplied function does not have C-linkage");
}

int main()
{
    assertCLinkage(my_func); // Should compile
    assertCLinkage(my_other_func); // Should NOT compile
}
```

Is there a possible implementation of `is_c_linkage` that would throw a compiler error for the second function, but not the first? I'm not sure that it's possible (though it may exist as a compiler extension, which I'd still like to know of). Thanks.

Comment: I strongly suspect this cannot be done - especially not in a standard manner.  Interesting question, though.

Comment: I'm not so sure about that. But even if it could be done, it's quite likely that GCC won't support it, because it doesn't know the distinction of an extern "C" and an extern "C++" function type. Thus it treats both types the same.

Comment: if you are going to implementation specific knowledge you may as well make it work for that implementation rather than throw an error

Comment: Ok, I'll assume that it's not possible (outside of there possibly being some esoteric compiler-specific hacks that I wouldn't expect anyone to know about). Thanks for the information and help, everyone. Is there anything I should do to mark the question as closed without there being an "answer", per se?

Comment: You could append "[unsolvable]" to the question title.

Comment: I believe my answer contains a Standard compliant way to solve your problem (which checks for non-C++-linkage instead which in practice would work equally well, i think). But even comeau doesn't like it. That's why i removed my answer.

Answer (score 2):

I agree with Jonathan Leffler that this probably is not possible in a standard way. Maybe it would be possible somewhat, depending on the compiler and even version of the compiler, but you would have to experiment to determine possible approaches and accept the fact that the compiler's behavior was likely unintentional and might be "fixed" in later versions.

With `g++` version 4.4.4 on Debian Squeeze, for example, you might be able to raise a compiler error for functions that are not `stdcall` with this approach:

```
void my_func() __attribute__((stdcall));
void my_func() { }

void my_other_func() { }

template <typename ret_, typename... args_>
struct stdcall_fun_t
{
    typedef ret_ (*type)(args_...) __attribute__((stdcall));
};

int main()
{
    stdcall_fun_t<void>::type pFn(&my_func),
        pFn2(&my_other_func);
}
```

`g++ -std=c++0x` fails to compile this code because:

> SO2936360.cpp:17: error: invalid conversion from ‘void (*)()’ to ‘void (*)()’

Line 17 is the declaration of `pFn2`. If I get rid of this declaration, then compilation succeeds.

Unfortunately, this technique does not work with `cdecl`.

Answer (score 0):

For Unix/Linux, how about analyzing the resulting binary with 'nm' and looking for symbol names? I suppose it's not what you meant, but still it's sort of compile time.